# Does Fortran array syntax influence speed or there is a compiler optimization fault?

Tags: performance, multidimensional-array, syntax, fortran

Let's have a double precision multidimensional array which needs to be initialized.

```
allocatable A(:,:,:)
! some code in which N1,N2,N3 are defined
allocate (A(N1,N2,N3))
```

We can initialize A in three syntax-wise ways:

```
A=0.d0
A(:,:,:)=0.0d0
A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3)=0.0d0
```

Which one would give the fastest execution time?
(to account for the variability of the execution time of the same code, neglect difference less than, say 20%)

Comments so far indicate that the execution time is not expected to be dependent on the syntax. However this test problem shows differently:

```
      program MatrixInit
      implicit double precision(A-H,O-Z)
      allocatable A(:,:,:)  

! writing file header      
      write(44,'(A,A)')'  N1 N2  N3       niter        tt1         tt2       ', &
                       ' tt3        tt4         tt2/tt4    tt3/tt4'
      
! Set the small dimensions N1 and N2 
! To hold, say, a stress tensor or a rotational matrix
      N1=3; N2=3    
         
! Set several examples with big N3 (say number of nodes)
      do i3=7,16
        N3=2**i3
         
        allocate(A(N1,N2,N3))
         
! Set the number of repetitions so that the times for the examples to be similar
        niter = (2**20)/(N1*N2*N3)*(2**12)
        
! NOTE: In the repetitions loop a duumy assignment is used so that the 
! initialization is not optimized to be out of the loop

! t1 convert matrix to vector - This the fastest
        call cpu_time(t0)
          do iter=1,niter
            A(1,1,1)=iter   
            call INIT(A,N1*N2*N3)
          enddo 
        call cpu_time(t1)

! t2: A=0.0d0
          do iter=1,niter
            A(1,1,1)=iter
            A=0.d0
          enddo 
        call cpu_time(t2)
      
! t3: A(:,:)=0.0d0
          do iter=1,niter
            A(1,1,1)=iter
            A(:,:,:)=0.d0
          enddo 
        call cpu_time(t3)

! t4: A(1:N2,1:N3)=0.0d0
          do iter=1,niter
            A(1,1,1)=iter
            A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3)=0.d0
          enddo 
        call cpu_time(t4)
! Times
        tt1=t1-t0   ! Time for vector initialization
        tt2=t2-t1   ! Time for A=0.d0
        tt3=t3-t2   ! Time for A(:,:,:)=0.d0
        tt4=t4-t3   ! Time for A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3)
      
        write(44,9)  N1,N2,N3,  niter, tt1,tt2,tt3,tt4, tt2/tt4,tt3/tt4 
       
        deallocate (A) 
      enddo
9     format(2i3,i6, 2x,i9, 6x, 4G11.4, 3x, 2G11.4)      
      end
      

      subroutine INIT(A,N)
      implicit double precision(A-H,O-Z)
      dimension A(N)
        A=0.0D0 
      return
      end
```

Compilation is done with Intel Fortran with Option /O2.
Below is the output from the WRITE(44,...) when the program is compiled and run on two computers:

On DELL Laptop: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3740QM CPU @ 2.70GHz   2.70 GHz, RAM 16.0GB

Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on IA-32, Version 18.0.0.124

```
  N1 N2  N3       niter        tt1         tt2        tt3        tt4         tt2/tt4    tt3/tt4
  3  3   128    3727360       0.6406      6.031      7.297      1.406         4.289      5.189    
  3  3   256    1863680       0.7188      6.266      7.219      1.234         5.076      5.848    
  3  3   512     929792       0.8906      5.984      7.172      1.328         4.506      5.400    
  3  3  1024     462848       0.9219      6.000      7.250      1.359         4.414      5.333    
  3  3  2048     229376       0.9531      5.875      7.109      1.312         4.476      5.417    
  3  3  4096     114688       0.9688      5.953      7.047      1.391         4.281      5.067    
  3  3  8192      57344        1.297      6.109      7.172      1.500         4.073      4.781    
  3  3 16384      28672        1.312      5.906      7.422      1.438         4.109      5.163    
  3  3 32768      12288        1.125      5.047      6.062      1.266         3.988      4.790    
  3  3 65536       4096       0.7656      3.453      4.047     0.8906         3.877      4.544
```

DELL Desktop: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.41 GHz, RAM 32.0GB
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 19.1.3.311

```
  N1 N2  N3       niter        tt1         tt2        tt3        tt4         tt2/tt4    tt3/tt4
  3  3   128    3727360       0.2969      4.125      5.281      1.141         3.616      4.630    
  3  3   256    1863680       0.2969      4.250      5.328      1.109         3.831      4.803    
  3  3   512     929792       0.5469      3.969      5.516      1.297         3.060      4.253    
  3  3  1024     462848       0.5156      4.188      5.453      1.297         3.229      4.205    
  3  3  2048     229376       0.5312      4.141      5.359      1.297         3.193      4.133    
  3  3  4096     114688       0.5781      4.156      5.328      1.359         3.057      3.920    
  3  3  8192      57344       0.6250      4.188      5.344      1.453         2.882      3.677    
  3  3 16384      28672       0.6406      4.094      5.328      1.453         2.817      3.667    
  3  3 32768      12288       0.5469      3.531      4.625      1.234         2.861      3.747    
  3  3 65536       4096       0.3750      2.359      3.047     0.8438         2.796      3.611
```

It is unexpected that  A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3)=0.d0 is from 3 to 5 times faster!
Could this be explained or is it some bug in the compiler?
NOTE: This big difference happens only when first dimensions are small and the last one is big.

When it is compiled with /Od  (without optimization) on the DELL Desktop the times are:

```
  N1 N2  N3       niter        tt1         tt2        tt3        tt4         tt2/tt4    tt3/tt4
  3  3   128    3727360        9.750      21.81      21.91      19.27         1.132      1.137    
  3  3   256    1863680        9.469      21.03      21.41      18.27         1.151      1.172    
  3  3   512     929792        9.203      20.61      21.61      18.72         1.101      1.154    
  3  3  1024     462848        9.422      21.14      21.20      18.39         1.150      1.153    
  3  3  2048     229376        9.281      20.91      21.34      18.66         1.121      1.144    
  3  3  4096     114688        9.484      20.83      21.17      18.42         1.131      1.149    
  3  3  8192      57344        9.594      21.33      21.27      18.52         1.152      1.149    
  3  3 16384      28672        9.578      21.14      21.23      18.22         1.160      1.166    
  3  3 32768      12288        8.203      18.23      17.91      15.55         1.173      1.152    
  3  3 65536       4096        5.297      12.08      12.55      10.98         1.100      1.142
```

Here A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3)=0.d0 is only 10% to 15% faster, but is persistently so (i.e. not due to random variations of the timings).

Compiled with Silverfrost FTN95 v8.80 (on the DELL Laptop) with Option /Op the timings are quite different:

```
  N1 N2  N3       niter        tt1         tt2        tt3        tt4         tt2/tt4    tt3/tt4
  3  3   128    3727360        2.469      2.484      10.97      13.45        0.1847     0.8153
  3  3   256    1863680        2.422      2.422      11.36      14.08        0.1720     0.8069
  3  3   512     929792        2.625      2.641      11.22      13.73        0.1923     0.8168
  3  3  1024     462848        2.563      2.594      11.33      13.55        0.1915     0.8362
  3  3  2048     229376        2.516      2.516      10.97      13.66        0.1842     0.8032
  3  3  4096     114688        2.688      2.672      11.27      13.52        0.1977     0.8335
  3  3  8192      57344        2.703      2.719      11.13      13.44        0.2023     0.8279
  3  3 16384      28672        2.672      2.734      11.27      13.44        0.2035     0.8384
  3  3 32768      12288        2.375      2.359      9.672      11.48        0.2054     0.8422
  3  3 65536       4096        1.594      1.594      6.719      7.906        0.2016     0.8498
```

Now A=0 is the fastest (same as the 'vector' subroutine) and A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3) is about 5 times slower.

gFortran v12.1, with option '-O', on DELL Laptop, gives:

```
  N1 N2  N3       niter        tt1         tt2        tt3        tt4         tt2/tt4    tt3/tt4
  3  3   128    3727360        1.297      1.203      1.219      1.234        0.9747     0.9873    
  3  3   256    1863680        1.219      1.219      1.203      1.234        0.9873     0.9747    
  3  3   512     929792        1.344      1.359      1.328      1.391        0.9775     0.9551    
  3  3  1024     462848        1.359      1.344      1.344      1.344         1.000      1.000    
  3  3  2048     229376        1.328      1.375      1.328      1.359         1.011     0.9770    
  3  3  4096     114688        1.359      1.375      1.359      1.359         1.011      1.000    
  3  3  8192      57344        1.438      1.453      1.453      1.438         1.011      1.011    
  3  3 16384      28672        1.438      1.438      1.453      1.453        0.9892      1.000    
  3  3 32768      12288        1.234      1.234      1.344      1.250        0.9875      1.075    
  3  3 65536       4096       0.8594     0.9062     0.8750     0.8594         1.055      1.018
```

The timings are practically the same for all discussed options of initialization, and they are close to Intel's best times.

18/07/2022. Did some testing and found that the way the array dimensions are defined is very important.
If N1 and N2 does not have constant values (say vary in a DO loop, or 'READ') the times to initialize A by the three syntaxes are similar and much slower than the subroutine vector initialization.
If N1 and N2 are assigned a constant, then we see the results presented above.
If N1 and N2 are given as parameters, then Intel compiler gives all times equal to the subroutine vector initialization time. For the Silverfrost compiler - only A=0 is as fast as the 'vector' time.

Comment: There is nothing inherent to Fortran that makes this answerable as each must have the same effect. For a practical situation you must give details of your system

Comment: And to add to the mix it is perfectly possible that loops, or a mixture of loops and array syntax will be quickest, and that which is the fastest will differ depending upon exactly which compiler flags are used, as well as a host of other things.

Comment: (If any compiler gives a difference of more than 20% in timing, you should report that as a bug.)

Comment: Intel fortran compiler v18 with option /O2  gives that 
A(1:N1,1:N2,1:N3)=0.0d0 is about 3 times faster than the other two.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to include the complete code you are using to perform this test. Without that discussion is mostly pointless

Comment: For the example given, `a(:,:,:) = 0.d0`, a smart compiler might recognize the array section is equivalent to the whole array and optimize this to a single function call, e.g., `memset(a, 0, size(a))`.  OTOH, a compiler might generate a triple nested do-loop and do `size(a)` assignments.  To me, trust your compiler.  Do `a = 0`.

Comment: Not a problem with gfortran.  Perhaps, change compilers?

Comment: See the problem with Intel 2021.6.0 on Linux. Second Steve that with gfortran 9.4 all variants, including calling the "1D" subroutine, give the same time, I suggest you report to Intel, but before you do stick `Implicit None` in the code as you should do in all code - I haven't checked that omitting this has introduced any bugs.